# Running Load Tests with a Build Agent

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing

I have been trying for a while and I am not able to run Load Tests with my Build Agent. I have a solution with different projects, running Coded UI Tests, Web Performance Tests; all of them running fine on the Build Agent. The problem is that I can't run Load tests.

I started thinking that it was not possible, but I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399135(v=vs.110).aspx#test) at Visual Studio online documentation:

> The build agent can run:
>
> Code Coverage
>
> Coded UI Tests (Requires a build server that is running in interactive
>   mode)
>
> Database Test Data Generation
>
> Database Unit Tests
>
> Generic Tests
>
> **Load Tests**
>
> Unit Tests
>
> Ordered Tests
>
> Test Impact Analysis
>
> Web Tests

So I guess it is possible somehow. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: "Cant' run" is very general. What happens when you try? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182465(v=vs.110).aspx . Do a web search for terms such as "visual studio run load test build agent".

Comment: I already have defined a Build like that but still I have to run my LoadTest manually. What happens when I queue my build is that all tests are executed fine and I can check the results, but not LoadTests. Something similar happened to Web Performance Tests at first, but there is "Generate code" button for this tests. Not the same for LoadTests.